# Fetch all the records without one attribute in dynamoDB using node

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am working with dynamoDB, AWS lambda function, serverless framework with the node.js runtime.
I want to fetch all the records from a particular table without a particular attribute.

In my case, the user table records like, Here id is a primary key

```
{
     id: 468caff0-630d-11e8-ada4-d5e26a6f9156,
     fullname: "a",
     email: "a@gmail.com",
     password: "abcd",
     address: "address 123"
     createdAt: "1527576930412"
}
{
    id: 468caff0-630d-11e8-ada4-d5e26a6f9155,
    fullname: "a",
    email: "a@gmail.com",
    password: "abcd",
    address: "address 123"
    createdAt: "1527576930412"
}
{
    id: 468caff0-630d-11e8-ada4-d5e26a6f9154,
    fullname: "a",
    email: "a@gmail.com",
    password: "abcd",
    address: "address 123"
    createdAt: "1527576930412"
}
{
    id: 468caff0-630d-11e8-ada4-d5e26a6f9153,
    fullname: "a",
    email: "a@gmail.com",
    password: "abcd",
    address: "address 123"
    createdAt: "1527576930412"
}
{
    id: 468caff0-630d-11e8-ada4-d5e26a6f9152,
    fullname: "a",
    email: "a@gmail.com",
    password: "abcd",
    address: "address 123"
    createdAt: "1527576930412"
}
{
    id: 468caff0-630d-11e8-ada4-d5e26a6f9151,
    fullname: "a",
    email: "a@gmail.com",
    password: "abcd",
    address: "address 123"
    createdAt: "1527576930412"
}
```

Now I dont't want to fetch `password` attribute when I fetch all the records of the user table.

Right now I did this with the help of `ProjectionExpression`
My current query is like

```
const params = {
    TableName: 'team',
    ProjectionExpression: "fullName, email, address, createdAt"
};

dynamoDb.scan(params, (error, result) => { 
    // here i got result without the password
})
```

In the above query i don't want to write this line `ProjectionExpression: "fullName, email, address, createdAt"`.
I just want to define the attribute which i don't want into the result.
So is there any way to this kind of things into dynamoDB query?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: There is no way for that.

Comment: This is not supported by the current API in DynamoDB. Is there a specific reason that you need this feature instead of using "ProjectionExpression"?

Comment: Hello Denis, Thanks for your answer. Above dynamoDB table's records is just for an example but there are multiple fields like role, state and etc. 
These are reserved keywords and when I try to pass into the `ProjectionExpression` then it through errors that's why I need that if there is any exist like we just pass the attributes which we don't want into the response.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the ProjectionExpression.

To use reserved keywords in a ProjectionExpression (or any other DDB Expression), you use ExpressionAttributeNames (and ExpressionAttributeValues if needed) to map them.

```
const ddbParams = {
    TableName: 'tableName',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#ro': 'role',
        '#st': 'state'
    },
    ProjectionExpression: '#ro, #st',
}
```

You **must** use the hash symbol `#`.

`ExressionAttributeValues` will use a colon `:` instead of a hash. In an update you would do `UpdateExpression: 'SET #ro = :ro'`.